# Flash Rollovers don't fire in Firefox

Tags: actionscript-3, firefox, rollover

latest Fp 11.1.102.55

Firefox v 3.5.2

OSX

My rollover events are not firing.
Every other browser works fine

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: With out code to work on I would say: Dont use firefox?

Comment: How about updating Firefox as a first attempt to solve the issue? Firefox 3.5.x is ancient, its support has been dropped almost a year ago. Firefox 3.5.2 in particular has [much bigger issues](http://www.mozilla.org/security/known-vulnerabilities/firefox35.html) than rollover events.

Comment: are you using wmode transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem in every Firefox version before 10, and it was because the swf did not have browser focus. Have you tried clicking on the swf then trying to trigger the rollover event?

I tried using jQuery to give the swf focus, but that just created more problems than it was worth. In the end I just lived with it. Sorry it's not much of an answer, but I still need two more rep points before I can just comment on stuff, haha.